# Value cannot be null error in Sitecore powershall report download

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am trying to generate report using powershell. I am getting results but when I tried to download report using powershell report dialog box throwing error as shown in below screenshot

[image]

Please see below code that I wrote to generate report, my Sitecore version is Sitecore 9 update 2 and powershell version is 4.7.2

```
$startPath = "master:/sitecore/content/Home"
Write-Host "Search started $(Get-Date -format 'u')"   
$linkProvider = [LM.Lightcore.Links.LinkProvider]::new()
$urlOptions = [Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions]::new();
$list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

$itemsToProcess = Get-ChildItem $startPath -Language * -Recurse

if($itemsToProcess -ne $null) {

    $itemsToProcess | ForEach-Object { 
         $match = 0;
         foreach($field in $_.Fields) {
                 if($field -match '.*__SearchText*') {
                      $item = Get-Item ("web:" + $_.ID)
                     $info = [pscustomobject]@{
                         "FullPath"=$_.Paths.FullPath
                         "ItemUrl"=$linkProvider.GetItemUrl($item, $urlOptions)

                     }
                     [void]$list.Add($info)
             }
         }
     }

}

Write-Host "Search ended $(Get-Date -format 'u')"

Write-Host "Items found: $($list.Count)"

$list | Show-ListView  

Close-Window
```

Thanks
Rishi

Comment: Add full stack trace of the exception instead of partial screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes due to the old version of `PowerShell` i.e. `4.7` which doesn't have proper support for `pscustomobject`.
Either upgrade version to at least `5.1` or be specific when calling to show-listview i.e. give actual field name to show in report like show-listview -property FullPath, ItemUrl.

Hope it gives you an idea of the resolution.